# Accessing coldfusion temp files through browser

Tags: coldfusion, temp

If I use [coldfusion's getTempDirectory()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/gettempdirectory.html) as the path to generate a file, is there any way for a browser to access that? Or, if not, can I configure the temp path to be a certain folder?

Comment: Some of us who might know the answer are too lazy to select your hyerlink.

Comment: The example in the documentation you point us to suggests that the answer is yes.  What did you unsuccessfully try that led you to posting this question?

Comment: So the directory is something like c:/user/temp. A browser can't access that, as far as I know.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg it can, if you tell your server to serve it.. probably not a good idea though. it's outside the webroot for a reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could serve the content using the [cfcontent](http://cfdocs.org/cfcontent) tag. It reads the file and sends the contents to the browser.

```
<cfcontent  
    type = "text/html"  
    file = "#getTempDirectory()#\myfile.htm"  
    deleteFile = "No">
```

Comment: Ahhh had no idea that existed. Brilliant.

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 100.  You owe me a beer.